# Open .VMX file in VMWare

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have `Ubuntu-12.4` installed on `VMWare` and I want to edit `.vmx` file to enable `KVM Virtualization`

I have seen a tutorial how to edit but can't find where the `.vmx` file is?

Comment: is your machine windows ? linux ?

Comment: Host is Windows 8 and I installed Ubuntu on VMWare

Answer (score 0):

If your host machine is Windows :

open command line, type in :

```
C:\>dir \*.vmx /s/p
```

If your host machine is Linux :

open command line (shell)

go to base folder

type in :

```
sudo find / -name "*.vmx"
```

or just (if you are root)

```
find / -name "*.vmx"
```

this will locate the file.

full explanation :

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003880